# What is the cornerRadius value of the iPad Safari app?

Tags: ios, ipad, uiview

I'd like to round the corner of my main view with `cornerRadius`, looks like the built-in Safari on iPad. What value should I put?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least in iOS 6 that rounding is automatic if you haven't got your controller's `wantsFullScreenLayout` to `YES`. Otherwise the radius is exactly what the name says so having zoomed in on the image it looks like you want a radius of 4 or 5.